# Mapping ActiveRecord class with MetadataTypeAttribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, orm, castle-activerecord

Is it possible to map an ActiveRecord class using the MetadataType attribute in order to keep the original class clean?
I have tried the following code but it didn't work:

```
[MetadataType(typeof(UserMetadata))]
public class User : ActiveRecordBase<User>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
}

[ActiveRecord("Users")]
public class UserMetadata
{
    [PrimaryKey("ID")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Property(Unique = true)]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Property]
    public string Password { get; set; }
}
```

ActiveRecord is simply not loading the mapping. I have also tried other combinations of attributes but none of them worked.
Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really a definitive solution, but I ended up using a **partial class** to clean my code.

Comment: P.S. it seems that, in order to use the associated meta class, a library must be **aware** of the MetadataType attribute, it is not automatic.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to try it with AutoMapper: http://automapper.org/

Comment: Unfortunately my mappings are for a quite old database and I didn't understand how AutoMapper is related to Castle ActiveRecord. Thanks.